# How can I dynamically load a foreign library?

Tags: haskell

Is there a Haskell equivalent of POSIX' `dlopen` or Windows' `LoadLibrary`? All the FFI stuff only seems to work with libraries specified at link time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick hoogling brings up [System.Posix.DynamicLinker](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.4.0.2/docs/System-Posix-DynamicLinker.html). You can also try the [plugins](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins) package for more high-level stuff.

For Windows, there is [System.Win32.DLL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.2.2.0/docs/System-Win32-DLL.html). The result of [getProcAddress](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.2.2.0/docs/System-Win32-DLL.html#v:getProcAddress) can be converted to a function pointer using [castPtrToFunPtr](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/docs/Foreign-Ptr.html#v:castPtrToFunPtr).

Comment: That's nice, but is there something platform independent?